# C#, WinForms - Starting Search Process with 'ENTER' Button

Tags: c#, winforms, search, button, enter

I am searching for a function that gives me the ability to start searching through my DGV without clicking on my 'Search' Button. Therefor I made a search button which starts the search process on click:

```
private int SearchValueRowIndex()
        {
            string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() == searchValue)
                    {
                        return cell.RowIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Not found
            return -1;
        }
```

The SearchValueRowIndex :

```
    private int SearchValueRowIndex()
    {
        string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() == searchValue)
                {
                    return cell.RowIndex;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I tried to open a new class for the activation of the SearchButton without a need to click on it:

```
 private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue.ToString() == Keys.Enter.ToString())
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I already tried a few changes, which didn't work out as well. There is no Error or Exception appearing, just nothing happens if I use the 'ENTER' Button.

Comment: Does the button have the focus when you press the key? If no then it will not capture the keyboard. Also, this is not necessary, as the keypress event will only happen when the focus is set to the button, it will raise the click event if you press the enter key.

Comment: and how to add the focus for the key then?

Comment: do you really need a button? I mean, the form can have it's KeyPreview property set to true and then it will receive any key press.

Comment: Uhm, no. I think I translated your answer in a wrong direction. Im trying to set the KeyPreview to true. Can't find it so far. Is there the possibility that it's not accessable?

Comment: Nope, but that property is on the form, not on the button, maybe that's why you can't find it.

Comment: Wow... thank you. Set it to true

Comment: does the form have the focus??

Comment: 'the focus' ? what do you mean with that? There is still nothing happening if I press ENTER-Button. I think there is no focus.

Comment: Is your window the top one and is selected? that means focus.

Comment: Yep, 100% sure because i am typing some name into the search textbox.

Comment: Then if you're typing on a text box, why complicate things? just hook to the KeyPress event of the textbox and check if it's the enter key.

Comment: Okay, that did work.. somehow. Needs to be changed a bit but atleast works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are typing search query in a search textbox. Then you can directly hook textbox.KeyDown event to get your required result.

```
    private void SearchTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //Perform search
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `KeyPreview`-Property of your Form to `true`.
Then you can implement the `KeyDown`-Event for all controls on your form like this:

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) this.button1_Click(sender, e);
}

private void txt_search_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) this.button1_Click(sender, e);
}
...
```

Comment: Did search with STRG+F, did find nothing. Where to add it?

Comment: In the Design-View of your Form there is a property in the Property-Window called KeyPreview.

Comment: Didn't find it. Searched through it and openend every subbutton it could hide below.

Comment: You also can set the property in the constructor of your form by writing this.KeyPreview = true;

Answer (score 0):

there is a property for the form called AcceptButton. This is called when enter is pressed. Maybe you can set this to your search button.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AcceptButton = button1;// button1 name of your button
        }
```